# Find substring in a string using start and end points from List

Tags: erlang, substring

I have a list like `List = [{0,12},{0,12},{-1,0},{0,12},{0,4},{1,2}]` and a string `Str = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQfdwsPao9E"`, now I've to find all the substrings using start and end point from list.

I want substrings to be returned in a List like `["https://www","https://www",..]`

I tried using this:

```
C=lists:map(fun({X,Y}) -> string:sub_string(Str,X,Y) end,List)
```

Comment: What's the exact output you're looking for? `-1` is not a valid index even if you're indexing from 0 (`string:sub_string` is indexed from 1).

Comment: @Dogbert The list which I generated is using `re:run` and I want to get substring of the indexes from `List`, in case index starts from `1`, then can you suggest a solution by modifying the `List` and then find substring.

Comment: Any reason not to just ask `re:run` to return strings? E.g. `re:run("foo", "(.)(.)", [{capture, all, list}]) == {match,["fo","f","o"]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1> List = [{0,12},{0,12},{-1,0},{0,12},{0,4},{1,2}].
[{0,12},{0,12},{-1,0},{0,12},{0,4},{1,2}]
2> Str = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQfdwsPao9E".
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQfdwsPao9E"
3> Len = length(Str).
43
4> [string:sub_string(Str,max(1,X),min(Len,Y)) || {X,Y} <- List].
["https://www.","https://www.",[],"https://www.","http",
 "ht"]
5>
```

you may have to adjust the indexes in the string to fit exactly to your need.

[edit] It looks like I didn't interpret correctly what is the meaning of the tuple. I think it is {Fist_Char_Index, Char_Number}, or {-1,0} if no match is found. So you should use:

```
[string:sub_string(Str,X+1,X+Y) || {X,Y} <- List, {X,Y} =/= {-1,0}].
```

Comment: Why `re:run` returns indexes like `{-1,0}` ?

Comment: when `List=[{0,37},{0,17},{0,4},{7,10},{7,7},{8,5},{-1,0},{-1,0},{-1,0},{-1,0},{-1,0}, {17,20}]` and  `Str="http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html"`, it shows a exception due to negative index generated on using `[string:sub_string(Str,max(1,X),min(Len,Y)) || {X,Y} <- List]` . `exception error: no function clause matching 
                    string:substr("http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html",
                                  8,-2) (string.erl, line 206)`